# Why use iBGP over eBGP?

Tags: routing, bgp

Why would you use iBGP over eBGP. i.e why use a single AS with an RR over multiple AS's using eBGP.
Is it simply for peering design simplification i.e large amount of devices all peering to a set of RRs?

Comment: Cisco has a knob called "always compare med" even if the meds are coming from different ASes

Comment: @Rolly, that would be for your single AS with MED coming from multiple ASes, which is the opposite of the question, where the OP is asking about using multiple ASes on his side. MED is not transitive among multiple ASes, unless you use confederations. It will not work with separate ASes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using iBGP, you the router must have a full mesh, or you must use a mitigation. Route reflectors are one mitigation. There is another mitigation that is similar to what you suggest, and it is called confederations. It basically breaks your AS in sub-ASes and uses eBGP between the sub-ASes.

You can search for BGP confederations, and you will find documents, such as [*IP Routing: BGP Configuration Guide*](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/iproute_bgp/configuration/15-mt/irg-15-mt-book/irg-int-features.html):

> ### BGP Routing Domain Confederation
>
> One way to reduce the internal BGP (iBGP) mesh is to divide an
>   autonomous system into multiple subautonomous systems and group them
>   into a single confederation. To the outside world, the confederation
>   looks like a single autonomous system. Each autonomous system is fully
>   meshed within itself and has a few connections to other autonomous
>   systems in the same confederation. Even though the peers in different
>   autonomous systems have external BGP (eBGP) sessions, they exchange
>   routing information as if they were iBGP peers. Specifically, the next
>   hop, Multi Exit Discriminator (MED) attribute, and local preference
>   information are preserved. This feature allows the you to retain a
>   single Interior Gateway Protocol (IGP) for all of the autonomous
>   systems.
>
> To configure a BGP confederation, you must specify a confederation
>   identifier. To the outside world, the group of autonomous systems will
>   look like a single autonomous system with the confederation identifier
>   as the autonomous system number.

Route reflectors are simpler to configure, and it is easy to screw up a confederation design and configurations. If you have a large AS, buying many AS numbers can be problematic, and confederations can internally use private AS numbers because you do not advertise them outside your AS. Some people like router reflectors, and some people like confederations. Having multiple, real ASes really isn't practical.

Comment: Thanks but the question is more around why use iBGP over eBGP. : )

Comment: The answer explains that. For eBGP, you need to buy a bunch of ASes, and you do not get the advantages of sharing non-transitive attributes and a single IGP. Confederations let you simulate eBGP inside your iBGP AS.

Comment: Not if you use private ASNs

Comment: Even if you use private AS numbers, you cannot share non-transitive attributes and use a single IGP. Confederations can use private AS numbers and allow you to do that.

Comment: @felix001, for example, if your AS uses a local preference attribute to route some traffic out one particular router, you cannot share that local preference to a different AS (hence, the name _local_ preference). With iBGP, you can, even with confederations that look like separate ASes inside your AS. MED and next hop do not work across different ASes either.

Comment: Perfect - this is the information I was after.

Comment: That information is contained in the answer. I simply repeated it.

Comment: Small point, med is used across AS

Comment: No, if you have multiple ASes you cannot use MED sent to you to determine out which path among ASes you should send traffic. You can only use MED to determine out which path inside a single AS to send traffic.

Comment: https://www.packetflow.co.uk/a-look-into-bgps-med-attribute/ the neighbor AS will use the MED to determine the ingress path

Comment: In on one neighbor AS, not among multiple neighbor ASes. If you have multiple ASes, and your neighbor sends MED to ask for a particular path, it will not work between your ASes because your ASes are separate ASes and do not share such information.